# Extjs, parsing JsonStore date

Tags: extjs, jsonstore

This is my JsonStore for grid.

```
var itemListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    id : 'itemListStore',
    proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url : 'test.php',
    }),
    totalCnt : 'totalCnt', // ?
    lastUpdate : 'lastUpdate', // ?
    root : 'content', // it works ok
    fields : [
        {name : 'name', type : 'string'},
        {name : 'id', type : 'string'},
    ],
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners : {
        load : function(){
            // I need to get the totalCnt and lastUpdate field value
            alert(this.lastUpdate); // output : lastUpdate -,.-
        }
    }
});
```

and the proxy data comes like this

{"totalCnt":95,"lastUpdate":"2011-08-01 09:20:03.000","content":[{"name":"MURRAY MP220GF..................

I can draw grid with content(root) but I can not get the totalCnt and lastUpdate field in load function.

anybody know this, please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by using:

```
itemListStore.proxy.getReader().rawData.totalCnt
```

UPDATE:
replaced `reader` with `getReader()`
Check out [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-property-rawData)

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, but there is an error. It says "itemListStore.proxy.reader is undefined". ?

Comment: @user682763, try `itemListStore.proxy.getReader().rawData.totalCnt`

Answer (score 2):

It should be `totalProperty` and not totalCnt

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
   ...config...
   totalProperty: 'totalCnt'
});
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your reply,then how about 'lastUpdate'? is it possible to get that?

Comment: I tried change totalCnt to totalProperty, and try again like this, listeners : {load : function(){alert(this.totalProperty);}} but still it does not working...do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can use `this.getCount()` to get the total number of records